# windows script for delete white space from file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a script that clear white spaces and write it to the console, but infact do nothing to file name -

```
@echo off&setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (
'dir C:\Inetpub\ftproot\MG_REPORTS\MG_PRO_\Network\Frank\ "* *"'
) do (set XX=%%~nxA)&echo ren "%%A"  "!XX: =!"
```

regards,

shamie

Comment: cpx: for 4 questions? Come on, do you only answer questions of people who accept each and every answer?

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop only sets `XX` to the last file name encountered. Also it probably loops over all files in the given directory and all file names containing spaces in the current working directory.

I'd do it the following way:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (C:\Inetpub\ftproot\MG_REPORTS\MG_PRO_\Network\Frank\*) do (
   set "FN=%%~nxf"
   set "FN=!FN: =!"
   ren "%%f" "!FN!"
)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. i don't kmow what the problem but it write to the console and not afect the file name at all

Comment: @shamir: If you actually want to rename the files, then remove the `echo` from the program. For bulk rename or delete operations it's common to test first whether the right files will be handled, thus the `echo`. I was assuming that you used it for similar reasons.

Comment: hi joey - first, thanks for your comments. second- i aware the meaning of 'echo', still after i delete the declaration i didn't succeed to rename the file name. ps - i am not familiar with batch file compare to shell so i feel like a blind man... :)

Comment: another thing  i am using windows server 2003

Comment: Change `echo ren "%%f" "%%~dpf!FN!"` to `ren "%%f" "!FN!"`; this drops the `echo` and drops the path of the `rename` target (only the *name* part is needed in the second argument)

Comment: mousio: Ouch, oversight on my part. Somehow I was assuming a recursive search for whatever reason ...

Comment: it is work! thank you all. do you know of good  batch tutorial?